# Adding new dishwasher. How do I connect hardwire to the power source under sink?

Tags: dishwasher

I got a really nice dishwasher for free and wanted to add it to my new ( older) two-story home. I’m trying to connect the hardwired dishwasher under the sink to the only power source. The garbage disposal runs to this same power source. ( see pic below). What should I do?! I’m afraid that if I have to run a wire from the circuit breaker below I won’t be able to reach it. The basement sits directly below kitchen.

enter image description here
[image]

Comment: What would you do? I want to resale the house. Do you think if I did that way I could resale it with the wiring hooked up that way?

Comment: It's unclear if the switch for the disposal is before or after this junction box, but in any case to be code compliant, you'd need to run a new circuit dedicated to the dishwasher.  Also, the white line doesn't appear to have a ground on it, and the wrapping of the ground from the yellow needs to be attached to the box via screw and not just under a cover screw.  Finally, I can see wire coming out of the yellow wirenut, which shouldn't be visible, so that should be reworked so all of the bare wire is protected by the wirenut.

Comment: To answer your question, there are lots of things you *could* do, but the only recommendation you'll get from this group is likely to do it properly and to code with a dedicated feed just for the dishwasher.

Comment: What are the nameplate ratings of the disposal and dishwasher?

Answer (score 3):

First, the code violations that exist here should be corrected.

The use of a metal box is excellent, and the use of cable clamps is at least correct. However, **boxes need lids**. The 2 screws on the corner *are not* for attaching ground wires, they are for attaching the lid.  The little nub in the corner has a hole tapped #10-32 and it takes a 10-32 NF machine screw - they even sell little ones painted green that are just right for the job.

Put a shepherd's hook on a #12 bare wire and attach it to that "nub" with a short #10-32 NF screw.  Then pigtail it to the ground wires from the 2 cables. Then obtain a 20 cent blank cover for a 4x4 steel box and slap it on there. If you lose those corner screws they are #8-32 NF.

Also, obtain a blank 1/2" knockout cover (my local hardware sells them for 10 cents a pop), pop the box off the wall, and insert the blank KO cover in the unused *but twisted out for no reason* knockout on the back center.

We don't know what's going on with the rest of this circuit. Fair chance the older Romex goes up to the disposal switch and we are looking at a *switch loop* here. More will need to be determined.

Since you're about to sell this house, it may not be legal for you to DIY work on it.  The  DIY exception for owner-occupants of single-family homes is because they have a vested interest in doing it right. If you're about to sell, no interest. Many localities recognize this fact and require licensed electricians. Since you need to be adding capacity to support a new appliance, definietly. If there had already been a washing machine there, different deal.

Answer (score 1):

Because the NEC's requirement is that a dishwasher must be placed on its own circuit, with a 120/125-volt, 15-amp breaker.

You should not try to run both on that circuit.

You will need separate cable (or plug) for the garbage disposal.

Answer (score -3):

It probably won't be code but should be safe. Put a duplex receptacle in the box or a CGFI or whatever your code requires. Then place an appropriately sized line cord on the dishwasher and plug it in. You probably will not be able to run one or the other but they will work. If the disposal is on a power switch instead of one of the automatic ones you will need to run a 12x3 with ground from the switch to this box.